# Grails save pdf of rendered page

Tags: pdf, grails

Is it possible to render view with all css, js... and
then save all generated html page in pdf?

I've tried solution with python libs:

- grails run-app localhost:3030
- dfkit/weasyprint visit page localhost:3030
- pdfkit/weasyprint save html as pdf

But weasyprint have problems with my local css and pdfkit fails too.
So I'd like to know wheter it is possible to render pdf for generated html from grails and what libs  should I use?

Comment: You can render pages from gsp templates using https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/rendering

Comment: @EvgenySmirnov, i have grails 3.3, added this plugin to build.gradle, imported in my controller, but pdfRenderingService thows exception "Cannot invoke method createDocument() on null object PdfRenderingService()"
I suppose that I should initialise it somehow, but I didn't find in rendering documentation or github how.

Comment: Do you have applied  web and gsp plugins in your build.gradle?

Comment: yes, and application works correctly when I do not try to save rendered page to pdf

Comment: runtime('com.lowagie:itext:2.1.0') ?